# How do i enable simulator option?

Tags: java, android

Actually i want to develop ios app in intelij using multi-os-engine module , i am facing the problem

ERROR
"
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:NewApp:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:NewApp:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:NewApp:classes UP-TO-DATE
:NewApp:moeMainProGuard
:NewApp:moeMainRetrolambda
:NewApp:moeMainDex
:NewApp:moeMainDebugX86Dex2Oat FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':NewApp:moeMainDebugX86Dex2Oat'.

  > The 'moeMainDebugX86Dex2Oat' task requires a macOS host or a remote build configuration.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED "

Plz anybody help me ????[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyxmZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like

> task requires a macOS host or a remote build configuration`

explains problem quite well. You need to run it on mac.

Comment: can i run ios app in windows ??

Comment: No. In order to develop IOS apps you must use macOS.

Comment: Actually i saw the tutorial in which he is using Intelij and installed the plugin  mulyi-os-engine module and develop ios app , but i am not sure that he is using mac or windows , do u have any idea about that .. thanks

Comment: I already answered your question, there is no sense to repeat that question many times - answer will be still the same.